# How to set default connection character set for php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small problem. I have russian characters in a database and I want to avoid setting `character_set_results` to utf8 all the time. Is there a way to hard set that ?

```
mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

I want to avoid this line and hard set it.

Thank you

Comment: In well designed application you only need this line once, so why avoiding it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

For czech language I use:

`mysql_query("set names latin2 collate latin2_czech_cs")`

Don't forget to set the proper collation too!